# adding special characters to file names on a mac

Tags: macos, fonts

I've just been sent a pdf file on my mac and the file name has a filled in circle instead of an 'o'. Can anybody tell me how they have done this. I've tried copying glyphs from other applications but that doesn't work. It's probably not a great thing to do but I'm just curious how it was done?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a glyph from a malformed font, and the creator named it using a non-USASCII letter, such as ø?

Comment: Is it a bullet "•" (option-8)?

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste the glyph into the Character Viewer - Language menu>Show Emoji and Symbols.
If you don't have the language menu up, then System Prefs > Keyboard > 'Show keyboard and emoji viewers in menu bar'.
Click the 'gear' icon top left, scroll down to Code Tables & check Unicode.

That will give you the name & Unicode number for the glyph.
For instance…
[image]
It's then a case of finding a font that can show it, though the system font replacer ought to be up to the task most of the time. Examples will be bottom right in the Character Viewer page.

You can search by typing 'circle' in the top right & see if you can see other similar glyphs, if copy/paste gives no good results.

Double-clicking any glyph you find will insert it at the current carat location.
Here are a few I found that way...

⬤⚫️⚫︎●•

Comment: I'm not sure anything in that last paragraph has been true for "other OSes" for quite some time.

Comment: @user1686 - you may indeed be right on that one - I threw up some pretty random unicode into a file name & both missed the same glyph - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CKuz.png